# Call an overloaded operator from GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I have this sample code for example :

```
class Test
{
    int var;
public:
    Test(int v_):
        var(v_)
    {}
    int operator()(int a)
    {
        return var + a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t = Test(10);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I call `operator()` of `Test` class from gdb when I'm in a breakpoint before the return ?

Commands like this one doesn't work :

```
(gdb) call (int)t.operator()((int)10)
```

And return :

```
Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not that the `operator()` is being *inlined*, but the linker is just removing the function, since is not called anywhere in your program.

On my machine, if I change `main` to:

```
int main()
{
    Test t = Test(10);
    t(42); // some call, result can be ignored
    return 0;
}
```

then running the command gives:

```
(gdb) call (int)t.operator()((int)10)
$1 = 20
```

Also, when compiling the program, use `-ggdb3` (for better debugging symbols) and `-O0` (so that function calls don't get inlined, etc).